# How set values in observable collection?

Tags: c#, mvvm, observablecollection

**I have this code:**

```
  private ObservableCollection<Workspace> _OpenWorkspaces;
  public ObservableCollection<Workspace> OpenWorkspaces {
                            get { return _OpenWorkspaces; }
                            set { _OpenWorkspaces = value; }
                                                 }
```

**How Can I set the values ?  (like this doesn't works)**

```
OpenWorkspaces.id =1; 
OpenWorkspaces.Name ="Jon";
```

Comment: Do you mean the items in the collection? e.g. `OpenWorkspaces.First().Name = "Jon"`;

Comment: Look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set a property of a specific item, you have to specify its index:

```
OpenWorkspaces[0].id =1; 
OpenWorkspaces[0].Name ="Jon";
```

If you want to do it for all items, use a loop:

```
foreach(var workspace in OpenWorkspaces)
{
    workspace.id =1; 
    workspace.Name ="Jon";
}
```

(assuming of course you already have items in the collection; you can add them with the `Add` method)

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection is like a List but is used mainly to show items on a View. You should use it like:

```
OpenWorkspaces.Add(yourWorkspace);
```

Where yourWorkspace has probably properties like Id and Name.

You can read  [Tutorial](http://wpfgrid.blogspot.com/2014/02/simple-observablecollection-wpf-mvvm.html)